# Reset PDF Settings and View back to default in IE 11

Tags: html, pdf

I currently open a pdf in an iframe. The iframe is hidden and whenever the user hits the button, the iframe loads the pdf source. When the window closes, it removes the source.

The problem that I have is that when a person views the iframe, messes with the zoom and pages, then closes down the iframe, the next person is stuck with the work that the other person was doing. Is there a way I can reset a pdf back to the default zoom, page, orientation, etc?

I've been doing some testing and it seems that adobe has a cache that will cache the settings until the browser closes down. An example is go to

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Mess with the zoom and pages, go to a different web page, and when you go back to that url, you'll see it's the exact same as you left it. I assume that there is a setting that I have to set in adobe reader. I've also tried setting defaults with parameters, but that doesn't seem to be working.

This is for internet explorer 11.

### Additional Info

this is for a kiosk system that is running IE11 in Kiosk mode. The shell has been replaced by ie, and it's set to load the site with the hidden iframe. The system is running Adobe Reader X 11.0 and I'm using the following to embed:

```
<object id="pdf" data="kill-charts.pdf" style="display: none;" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">
</object>
```

I've tried embed as well, but it doesn't make a difference. I swapped to object because I wanted to try with parameters. I tried this

```
<object id="pdf" data="kill-charts.pdf" style="display: none;" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">
<param name="zoom" value="100" />
</object>
```

but that didn't work after the second load.

Comment: as implied by the answer, it's not he pdf that is being saved, it's the pdf reader. you can't control other applications from the browser. also, you shouldn't assume everyone has a pdf plugin in their browser.

Comment: This is actually for a kiosk computer, so I have control on what settings I set and what software I can install. I do agree with what you said about the pdf not being saved. I understand it's not getting "saved", but rather "cached". If I close down the browser and load it up again, it resets the settings, but that's not an option because I'm running in kiosk mode. I'm willing to make any changes to adobe pdf reader as well, so any settings that might help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have access to a backend language you could easily kill and restard adobe reader. Php?

Comment: Unfortunately we are running the site as a pure HTML site, so there's no back end language. I'm sure I'm just missing a setting on adobe reader, but I'm just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you look on the last page of the link you provided you will see that you can append `#zoom=50` to the URL as follows:

```
http://example.org/doc.pdf#zoom=50
```

This will make the browser open it at 50% every time. You can also add other parameters as well such as page number:

```
http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=1&zoom=50
```

This method will work at least for the Adobe plug-in, but not guaranteed for other PDF plug-ins.

Comment: I've tried using this method. It works for the initial load, but once the settings are set the parameters no longer work.

Comment: so I just tried your suggestion just in case I was mistaken. The url I used was http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=1&zoom=50. The initial load works perfectly, but once I start zooming and changing pages, refreshing and navigating away from the page and back to the same url don't set it to page 1 @ 50%